# setBackgroundDrawable on multiple items not working properly

Tags: android

I have a gallery which has 7 + linear layouts in each view, and I set the background drawable for 7 of these layouts dynamically, depending on data I pull from out db, the position of the gallery, etc.

I have a for loop that launches 7 threads to fetch data and fetch the information needed for the drawables to be generated, all of which returns via a common handler, which in turn fetches each of the linear layouts and runs setBackgroundDrawable() on each of them.

The problem I'm running into is that I can see my constructors for the drawable being run 7 times, but draw() is only called on 1 or 2 of them. If I scroll right or left, the same thing happens with the new view. However, if I scroll back to the already drawn screen, all 7 of the linear layouts have their backgrounds drawn properly.

I've tried calling invalidate() and requestLayout() on the linear layouts, their parents, the gallery, but to no avail.

I would post my code but there is a whole mass of it, and I'm crossing my fingers that my explanation provides enough background. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to count the number of threads as I launched them, and once the last one had returned, call invalidate() on the parent layout. I had tried calling invalidate() every time one of them returned, but it looks like overall, things were simply happening too rapidly.